# Resonance frequency of microstrip resonator

Tags: resonator

An open circuit microstrip resonator was simulated as shown below. As we can see from the smith chart, the resonator we get the input impedance purely resonant at f0 = 4.33GHz.

The length of the microstrip is L = 20mm.

Given the formula shown below how do I show that at f0 input impedance is  purely resistive?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the obvious - realize the denominator and then set the imaginary part of the numerator to zero?  It drops out pretty easily.